# Regex for getting a string within characters, with first character set optional in Presto/Athena

Tags: regex, presto, amazon-athena

I've been banging my head around this one all, day. I got it to work in various online regex tools, but whenever I use it on the query the result is wrong.

I have data in my DB like this:

```
AMAZON PAYMENTS EUROPE S.C.A.
1/asdfL GE#EFRDA^9212 GRIFF
Frau HUSEL G^9212 GRIFF
```

I want to extract the text within `1/` and `^` when they are present. Like this:

```
AMAZON PAYMENTS EUROPE S.C.A.
asdfL GE#EFRDA
Frau HUSEL G
```

I tried many variations, and they all work online:

- Non Capturing group:  `^(?:1\/)?(.*?(?=\^|$))`
- Backward Looking: `(?<=1\/)(.*?(?=\^|$))`
- Conditional Expression: `(?(?=^1)1/(.*?(?=\^|$))|((^.*?(?=\^|$))))`

But when I run the query in the AWS I always get the `1/` back in the extract.

Anyone has a clue on how to go around this?

Comment: Are you using Presto? `REGEXP_REPLACE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
regexp_replace([column], '^(?:[^/]*/)?([^^]*)\^.*', '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hFtgJX/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^/]*/)?` - an optional sequence matching any zero or more chars other than a `/` and then a `/` char
- `([^^]*)` - Capturing group 1 (referred to from the replacement pattern with `$1`): any zero or more chars other than a `^`
- `\^` - a literal `^` char
- `.*` - the rest of the string to the end.